# Ionic error - package.json file seems malformed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

On running ionic serve in ionic project..

**ionic serve**

**[ERROR] The package.json file seems malformed.**

and command gets terminated.
How to fix this error?

package.json file:

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.3",
    "firebase": "^3.9.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic-native": "1.3.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: You seems to have an error in your package.json syntax... Show us this file.. we can't help you without somethink

Comment: Thanks Leo R. I just added package.json file.

Comment: How did you build your app ? your package.json is missing a lot of parameter lik name, version, description...

Comment: Thanks Leo R. Adding name and version fields in package.json file solved this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your complete package.json file please, read [this documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) and complete it with, at least, the required elements.

I think name and version fields will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! Adding name and version fields in package.json file solved this problem.